# Best way to compare nullable DateTimeOffset variables?

Tags: c#, nullable, comparison-operators, datetimeoffset

I have code that intends to take the largest of two `DateTimeOffset?` variables. I have been doing this using the following code:

```
return firstTimestamp > secondTimestamp ? firstTimestamp : secondTimestamp
```

However, as described by the MSDN documentation, if either of the values is null then the operation always resolves to `False`. This means that if a value is in `firstTimestamp`, and `secondTimestamp` is null, then null is returned where `firstTimestamp` should be returned.

Is there an efficient short-hand way of doing this comparison accounting for null values? The only solution I can think of is something like:

```
if(firstTimestamp.HasValue && secondTimestamp.HasValue){
    return firstTimestamp > secondTimestamp ? firstTimestamp : secondTimestamp;
}else if(firstTimestamp.HasValue){
    return firstTimestamp;
}
return secondTimestamp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Nullable.Compare<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.compare?view=netcore-3.1) method for that

```cs
DateTimeOffset? firstTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset? secondTimestamp = null;

var result = Nullable.Compare(firstTimestamp, secondTimestamp) > 0 ? firstTimestamp : secondTimestamp;
```

If `firstTimestamp` is not `null` and `secondTimestamp` is `null`, it returns a value, greater then `0`, and vise versa. Then you can use this value in [conditional operator `?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to get an expected result.